# Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle Data Migration (Conversion) (Other RDBMS ok, too)

Tags: oracle, migration, rdbms

Can you please give some tips or guidelines, best practices for MicroSoft SQL server to Oracle Data Migration? IMHO, it is something that comes best with experience. So I would like to benefit from your experience. Please share any insights that you have into design, modeling, testing or tuning for a data migration project. I would really appreciate if you share your experience even if it is not between these two RDBMSs.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle offers a free IDE, SQL Developer, which includes a Migration Workbench to support moving data from MS SQL to Oracle.  [Check it out.](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration/workbench/index_sqldev_omwb.html)