# Best way to migrate export/import from SQL Server to oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, import, export

I'm faced with needing access for reporting to some data that lives in Oracle and other data that lives in a SQL Server 2000 database. For various reasons these live on different sides of a firewall. Now  we're looking at doing an export/import from sql server to oracle and I'd like some advice on the best way to go about it... The procedure will need to be fully automated and run nightly, so that excludes using the SQL developer tools. I also can't make a live link between databases from our (oracle) side as the firewall is in the way. The data needs to be transformed in the process from a star schema to a de-normalised table ready for reporting.

What I'm thinking about is writing a monster query for SQL Server (which I mostly have already) that will denormalise and read out the data from SQL Server into a flat file using the sql server equivalent of sqlplus as a scheduled task, dump into a Well Known Location, then on the oracle side have a cron job that copies down the file and loads it with sql loader and rebuilds indexes etc.

This is all doable, but very manual. Is there one or a combination of FOSS or standard oracle/SQL Server tools that could automate this for me? the Irreducible complexity is the query on one side and building indexes on the other, but I would love to not have to write the CSV dumping detail or the SQL loader script, just say dump this view out to CSV on one side, and on the other truncate and insert into this table from CSV and not worry about mapping column names and all other arcane sqlldr voodoo...

best practices? thoughts? comments?

edit: I have about 50+ columns all of varying types and lengths in my dataset, which is why I'd prefer to not have to write out how to generate and map each single column...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484814/microsoft-sql-server-to-oracle-data-migration-conversion-other-rdbms-ok-too

Comment: no I read that question before I posted, the answer recommends oracl sql developer and the migration workbech. as stated in the question this needs to be scripted to run automatically, sql  developer requires user driving unless I miss my guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The data needs to be transformed in the process from a star schema to a de-normalised table ready for reporting."

You are really looking for an ETL tool. If you have no money in the till, I suggest you check out the Open Source Talend and Pentaho offerings.

Comment: hmmm will definitely have to look into those options. I'm working as a consultant so I'm not interested in pushing an expensive solution for a simple problem. ETL sounds like pretty much what I'm doing, with the caveat that I need to set up the job on 2 sides of a firewall... :-(