# Migration tool from TSQL to PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

We need to migrate our database from MSSQL to Oracle and we have over 100 stored procedures written in <strike>PL/SQL</strike> TSQL. I know its a long shot, but has anybody ever successfully used an automatic migration tool to do the work? I've seen some tools on the web, but I have no way to judge their ability to handle various code. Any personal experience in the matter would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle Data Migration (Conversion) (Other RDBMS ok, too)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484814/microsoft-sql-server-to-oracle-data-migration-conversion-other-rdbms-ok-too)

Comment: "We need to migrate our database from MSSQL to Oracle and we have over 100 stored procedures written in PL/SQL." This does not make sense. If you are converting from MSSQL to Oracle, then surely your stored procedures are written in T-SQL, and you want them converted to PL/SQL... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [SwisSQL - SQL Server to Oracle Migration Tool 3.5](http://www.swissql.com/products/sqlserver-to-oracle/sql-server-to-oracle.html);
2. [tsql to pl sql](http://www.download32.com/tsql-to-pl-sql-software.html);
3. [Convert SQL Server T-SQL to Oracle PL/SQL (syntax and equivalences)](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convent_sql_server_tsql_oracle_plsql.htm);

However, there are some optimisation that may be required to perform after the conversion is done. So, you should consider revising the conversion after it is done.

**EDIT #1**

Another interesting tool would be:

[Spectral Core's Full Convert Enterprise](http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/)

> Do you have experience with any of them?

Unfortunately not. I have just performed conversions to SQL Server using SSIS.

**EDIT #2**

There seems to be a more appropriate tool directly from Oracle that I would better trust.

Directly from Oracle: [Migrating from Microsoft SQL Server to Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html)

And the core features:

> **SQL Developer Migration technology supports the following core features when migrating from Microsoft SQL Server:**

- Automatically converts column data types to appropriate Oracle data types.
- Automatically resolves object name conflicts, such as conflicts with Oracle reserved words.
- Parses and transforms T-SQL stored procedures, functions, triggers, and views to Oracle PL/SQL.
- Provides advanced customization capabilities such as the ability to change data type mappings,   delete and rename objects.
- Generates reports about the status of the migration.
- Generates the DDL scripts for the creation of the destination Oracle database.
- Generates scripts for data movement
- Displays informational, error, and warning messages about the migration in a progress window.

  1. So, I would suggest that you look out everything in details that is not above-mentionned;
  2. Take a good look to the information details provided by the tool;
  3. Test your stored procedures after they are converted.

If you take a look as what SQL Server doesn't offer in comparison to Oracle, these are points where I would look first. In order to know these differences, follow the `3. Convert SQL Server T-SQL to Oracle PL/SQL (syntax and equivalences)` link above.

Comment: Do you have experience with any of them? How close do they come to working? Did you encounter any subtle errors I should look out for?

Comment: Please see my edits for answers. Yet 100 stored procedures is not a lot of work to do by hand, if you're comfortable with Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: The translation is not what I'm worried about, it's the testing the daunts me. But I guess there is no way to avoid that. We're probably going to write a unit test suite in Java that will be able to run against both Oracle and SQL Server and act as a regression tool.

Thanks for your in-depth answer and research.

Comment: This was a pleasure to provide you with information I searched for. I do hope this does help you along the migration. Please, let me know afterwards the practice that you have been through so that I can better learn myself. Thanks for accepting my answer, I appreciate it, sincerely. Have a good day! =)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest doing it by hand.  First, to me, personally, a 100 doesn't sound too bad at all.  I'd bet that your development follows patterns - using getutcdate() instead of current_timestamp, etc. This means, there probably are a few very repetitive problems that you and your team will be able to learn from.  To me, this will hold the added benefit of teaching you PL/SQL nuances/extensions, which you'll probably need to learn in order to maintain / expand the new system.

Good luck!

Comment: Doing it by hand is the default option we were going with, but I thought I'd see if there was a simpler way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I tried to do the opposite, but I'm afraid there's no 100% reliable way. Some features are unique to each RDBMS and can't be replicated by a tool (for example IDENTITY fields in SQL Server vs Sequences in Oracle). Considering that, at the end, I had to review each Stored Procedure to ensure it does what it's supposed to do, I realized it was better to plan a manual port and learn some PL/SQL while doing it.